# AngularJS - Display button on successful input collection entry

Tags: html, angularjs

I can't seem to update my ng-if to update on input entry and completion of entire row of input controls.  I want to evaluate ng-if (look at button)  each time I enter a new data in the form and under the condition that the entire row has entry to enable the last button (last column of row).

Should I use ng-model, ng-change, I am unclear on how to re-evaluate the ng-if.

Sample form

[image: Form]

Desired Behavior

[image: desired]

I want the buttons (+) to appear to the right of the input row (see last table, the third table on page) after user has entered all fields for that row.

How do I do it, as currently no change happens to ng-if?

```
  <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="event in [0,1,2,3,4,5]">
                                <td>
                                    {{event}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabled(event)}}" ng-show="ctrl.config.eventtitle{{event}}.done" config="eventtitle{{event}}" webix-ui="eventtitle{{event}}" width="250" height="30" type="text" id="eventtitle{{event}}" name="eventtitle[{{event}}]"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabled(event)}}" ng-show="ctrl.config.owner{{event}}.done" ng-model="ctrl.risk.owner[event]" config="owner{{event}}" webix-ui="owner{{event}}" id="owner{{event}}" width="250" height="30" name="owner[{{event}}]" options="users" type="richselect" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabled(event)}}" ng-show="ctrl.config.actualdate{{event}}.done" config="actualdate{{event}}" webix-ui="actualdate{{event}}" id="actualdate{{event}}" width="200" height="30" name="actualate[{{event}}]" value="today" type="datepicker" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabled(event)}}" ng-show="ctrl.config.scheduledate{{event}}.done" config="scheduledate{{event}}" webix-ui="scheduledate{{event}}" id="scheduledate{{event}}" width="200" height="30" name="scheduledate[{{event}}]" value="today" type="datepicker" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    H 5-5
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabled(event)}}" ng-show="ctrl.config.likelihood{{event}}.done" config="likelihood{{event}}" webix-ui="likelihood{{event}}" width="30" height="30" type="text" id="likelihood{{event}}" name="likelihood[{{event}}]"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabled(event)}}" ng-show="ctrl.config.technical{{event}}.done" config="technical{{event}}" webix-ui="technical{{event}}" width="30" height="30" type="text" id="technical{{event}}" name="technical[{{event}}]"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabled(event)}}" ng-show="ctrl.config.schedule{{event}}.done" config="schedule{{event}}" webix-ui="schedule{{event}}" width="30" height="30" type="text" id="schedule{{event}}" name="schedule[{{event}}]"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabled(event)}}" ng-show="ctrl.config.cost{{event}}.done" config="cost{{event}}" webix-ui="cost{{event}}" width="30" height="30" type="text" id="cost{{event}}" name="cost[{{event}}]"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button ng-if="ctrl.evtValid[event]" ng-model="ctrl.evtValid[event]" ng-click="ctrl.enable(event+1)">+</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

**Valid Method for a specific row of inputs**

```
     commonFunctions.evtValid = function(evt){
         return (
            document.querySelector("#eventtitle"+evt+ " input[type=text]") != null
         && document.querySelector("#eventtitle"+evt+ " input[type=text]").value != ''
         && document.querySelector("#owner"+evt+ " div.webix_el_box div.webix_inp_static")  != null
         && document.querySelector("#owner"+evt+ " div.webix_el_box div.webix_inp_static").outerText != ''
         && document.querySelector("#actualdate"+evt + " div.webix_el_box div.webix_inp_static") != null
         && document.querySelector("#actualdate"+evt + " div.webix_el_box div.webix_inp_static").innerHTML != ''
         && document.querySelector("#scheduledate"+evt+ " div.webix_el_box div.webix_inp_static") != null
         && document.querySelector("#scheduledate"+evt+ " div.webix_el_box div.webix_inp_static").innerHTML != ''
         && document.querySelector("#likelihood"+evt+ " input[type=text]") != null
         && !commonFunctions.invalidLevel(document.querySelector("#likelihood"+evt+ " input[type=text]").value)
         && document.querySelector("#technical"+evt+ " input[type=text]") != null
         && !commonFunctions.invalidLevel(document.querySelector("#technical"+evt+ " input[type=text]").value)
         && document.querySelector("#schedule"+evt+ " input[type=text]") != null
         && !commonFunctions.invalidLevel(document.querySelector("#schedule"+evt+ " input[type=text]").value)
         && document.querySelector("#cost"+evt+ " input[type=text]") != null
         && !commonFunctions.invalidLevel(document.querySelector("#cost"+evt+ " input[type=text]").value) );   
    }
```

**Directive Config Code**

```
    angular.module('Risk').directive('config', ['$timeout', ConfigElement]);

function ConfigElement($timeout){
      var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linkFn,
            controller: ConfigController
      }

      function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs){ 
            var attr = attrs.config;
            var type = attrs.type;
            var width = attrs.width;
            var height = attrs.height; 
            var evt;
            if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('class'))
            {
                var evt = parseInt(attrs.class[3]);

                if (scope.ctrl.evtValid.hasOwnProperty(evt))
                    scope.ctrl.evtValid[evt] = false;   
            } 

            var disabled = false;
            if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('enabled') && attrs.enabled == 'false')
                disabled = true;
            var maxlength = attrs.hasOwnProperty('maxlength')? attrs.maxlength: null;  
            var options = attrs.hasOwnProperty('options')? attrs.options : null;
            var view;

            if (type == "level")
                view = "text";
            else
                view = type;

            scope.ctrl.DOMops.setValidationServiceObj(scope.ctrl.ValidationService);
            scope.ctrl.DOMops.setValue('risk', scope.ctrl.risk);
            scope.ctrl.DOMops.setValue('riskMatrix', scope.ctrl.riskMatrix);   
            scope.ctrl.DOMops.setValue('risklevels', scope.ctrl.risklevels);

            scope.ctrl.ValidationService.setValue('risk', scope.ctrl.risk);
            scope.ctrl.ValidationService.setDOMobj(scope.ctrl.DOMops);


            var config = 
            {
                view: view,     
                responsive: true,
                width: width,
                height: height,
                disabled: disabled
            };

            if (view == "text" || view == "textarea")
            {
                config.on = {
                    "onTimedKeyPress": function(){  
                        var obj = this.eventSource || this; 
                        code = this.getValue();                                                 
                        scope.ctrl.ValidationService.getTextValueAndValidate(code, scope.ctrl, obj, attr);  
                        if (type == "level")
                            scope.ctrl.DOMops.assignRiskLevel(obj); 
                        if (evt != null)
                            scope.ctrl.evtValid[evt] = scope.ctrl.ValidationService.evtValid(evt); 
                    }
                }
                config.value = scope.ctrl.risk[attr];
            }
            else if (view == "richselect")
            {
                config.value = scope.ctrl.risk[attr];
                config.options = scope.ctrl[options];

                config.on =  {
                    "onChange": function(){
                        var obj = this.eventSource || this; 
                        scope.ctrl.getItemValueAndValidate(obj, scope.ctrl, attr);
                        config.value = obj.getValue(); 
                        if (evt != null)
                            scope.ctrl.evtValid[evt] = scope.ctrl.ValidationService.evtValid(evt); 
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (view = "datepicker")
            {
                config.timepicker = false;
                //multiselect: true,
                config.suggest = {
                    type:"calendar", 
                    body:{
                        minDate:(new Date()).setDate(new Date())
                    }                                         
                }      
                config.on = {
                    "onChange": function(){
                        var obj = this.eventSource || this; 
                        scope.ctrl.getDateValueAndValidate(obj, scope.ctrl, attr);
                        config.value = obj.getValue(); 
                        if (evt != null)
                            scope.ctrl.evtValid[evt] = scope.ctrl.ValidationService.evtValid(evt); 
                     }
                }   
            }

            if (maxlength)
                config.attributes = {maxlength : maxlength};
            config.done = true;
            scope.ctrl.config[attr] = config;
      }

      return directive;     
}


function ConfigController($scope, $element, $attrs){
    $scope.ctrl.config[$attrs.config] = {done: false};
}
```

Comment: Why do you not use `ng-disabled`? Are you aware the standard HTML doesn't support an `enabled` attribute?  And what effect do you expect `enabled="true"` to have on a `<div>`?

Comment: Fortunately enbaled="" works because I have a directive that handles that condition for a custom attribute,  it is rather the button that does not change behavior on text entry or drop down selection of my directive which if needed I can post code for.

Comment: demo site here: http://projectaim.ddns.net/#!/risk/edit/1   (see bottom table for demonstration)

Comment: @georgeawg, if I understand your comment I need to modify to be an id (by appending a # prefix), I have always used string concatenation for document.getElementById as I presently am for dynamic value computation

Comment: document.getElementById modified to have '#' prefix

Comment: The [.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method takes an ID string argument, not a query selector. The `evtValid` function is never going to return `true`. The `ng-if` condition is never going to be `true`.

Comment: Thanks George,  however, the original question still remains.

Comment: scope.$apply() in directive after the update of my scope variable fixes issue, however, immediately the text box clears on first type,  How do I prevent this?

Answer (score -1):

You can call the method in `ng-blur` to change a flag attribute. It will be executed  when an element has lost focus.

On `ng-if` you put the flag attribute condition.

[ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

Comment: Thanks Lucas,  I am actually trying to restrict while focused in the element as the type event, I wonder if there is an ng-change, however I still need to evaluate the button ng-if which is not part of the input collection