# AngularJS - How to prevent input values from undesirably clearing on ng-click button press

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webix

I have an issue which I believe is related to a $digest / $apply happening in my application causing the inputs to clear when I press the "+" button in a particular row of my inputs.

**How do I properly prevent input values from clearing on ng-click button press?**

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in [0,1,2,3,4,5]">
    <td>
        <div class="evt{{event}}" enabled="{{ctrl.enabledItem[event]}}"
             ng-show="ctrl.config.cost{{event}}.done" config="cost{{event}}"
             webix-ui="cost{{event}}" width="30" height="30"
             type="text" id="cost{{event}}" name="cost[{{event}}]">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" id="evt{{event}}" ng-if="event != 5" 
               style="display:none" ng-click="ctrl.enable(event)"
               value="+">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Sample screenshot before button click (with inputs filled out completely)

[image]

Please see http://projectaim.ddns.net/#!/risk/edit/1

See http://jsfiddle.net/02Lv1s9d
for an MCVE (minimal complete verifyable example)

First row of target table must be completely filled out for + button to appear and + button must be clicked to trigger the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Unfortunately an MRE is difficult to create here, suggestions are appreciated

Comment: I see you are using webix framework with angular. How does the model binding suppose to work?

Comment: In my related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708648/angularjs-display-button-on-successful-input-collection-entry    I have the entire directive code for webix data binidng.   For some reason, I think 2 way binding does not work out of box so I created a directive code to handle updates and binding

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** If you’re not sure what the source of the problem is, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back. A minimal example doesn't need 11 columns and 5 rows.

Comment: removal of ng-click="ctrl.enable(event)" stops the problem but prevents me from updating the necessary next row to be enabled

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/02Lv1s9d/ for an MCVE (minimal complete verifyable example) to the best of my ability.  And now I await a response...

Comment: Any Suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: There is no plus button in the fiddle.

Comment: @MunimMunna,  you need to type data into the first now completely and the dropdown along with the two datepickers

Comment: Still there is no button or any drop-down.

Comment: I apologize, enter 5 for "Like" "Tech" "Sched" "Cost" or any integer from 1-5 that is, I validate and forgot to include in my problem description.  You are correct, I don't have a drop down, just enter the remaining first row fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed it right, it's an angularJS digest issue. You have a `$element.ready` event in
`webix-ui` directive which does not call `$scope.$digest()` at the end, so changes within
this event handler is not digested when the page loads and elements are rendered.

The digest cycle runs when you click the plus button for the first time re-rendering
your UI. To solve this just add `$scope.$digest()` at the end of the event handler.

```
$element.ready(function() {
    // Here goes all existing code
    // Add the following block to enable the row
    let rowIndex = dataname[dataname.length - 1];
    $scope.$watch(() => $scope.$parent.enabledItem[rowIndex], isEnabled => {
        $scope.config[dataname].disabled = !isEnabled;
        watcher();
    });
    // call digest at the end
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

**N.B:** There are some places you are using native JavaScript `setTimeout`,
use `$timeout` instead which takes care of digest cycles.

**Update:**

To enable next row you have to add the watcher as I did above, and change click
event binding.

```
<input type="button" ng-click="enable(event)">
```

to

```
<input type="button" ng-click="enable(event + 1)">
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  it works now,  no clearing,  can you quickly possibly advise how I can enable the next row as I forgot the ask this in my question.  I can award bounty.  I want to enable on button + press.

Comment: I suggest you optimize your code base, right now it's a bit angular, a bit raw JavaScript, and variable name's are totally unpredictable, take some time to optimize, will save lot of time to maintain and debug.

Comment: My enable is based off attribute in the div tag that gets read into webix code directive for enabling is there a way to re evaluate the ‘enabled’ (my own custom name) attribute value and rebind.

Comment: One more question, to avoid re opening a new question,  how do I re-disable a row of inputs that have values in them and not clear the values too?   Your answers have proven to be very beneficial.

Comment: Please send me a cleaner jsfiddle in chat, we will see what can we do.

Comment: I think I got a solution that I want to post, how to I open a chat to post?  I can open a new answer too to show my answer.